# PHPExcel and Mpdf not generating file

Tags: php, phpexcel, mpdf

I'm generating a template using PHPExcel and then I want it to be converted to a PDF file using Mpdf. I'm using PHPExcel 1.7.8 and Mpdf 6.0

But the problem is that

1. The PDF file is not generated
2. The browser wants to display the generated file.

My Code

```
    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
    $rendererLibrary = 'mpdf';
    $rendererLibraryPath = APPPATH.'plugins/' .
    $rendererLibrary;
    if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
                 $rendererName,
                 $rendererLibraryPath
           )) {
           die(
                 'Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
                 PHP_EOL .
                 ' as appropriate for your directory structure'
    ); }

    $filename = "DWG Register.pdf"; //save workbook to a file name

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'PDF');          
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

Comment: `The PDF file is not generated
The browser wants to display the generated file.` sounds like a contradiction. What exactly is happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to file to be downloaded. If I generate the file is xlsx it works perfectly, but as soon as I implement the code above the file is not generated or download and safari shows the view for displaying a pdf file, but there is nothing (the page is gray)

Comment: Any errors being written to the logs? Does it create a file successfully if you save to the server rather than to php://output?

Comment: Please can you let me where to find the logs and how to save the file to the server. I'll check the logs and post the data.

Comment: Your webserver logs are generally in `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: How to save the file to the server? change the location the save to point to a filepath on the server rather than to php://output

Comment: @MarkBaker see the server log when generating the pdf file. `[Mon Sep 05 20:26:21.894952 2016] [:error] [pid 84623] [client ::1:60779] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 309408 bytes) in /Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/application/plugins/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 14488, referer: http://localhost:8080/codeigniter/index.php/dwg_issue/dwg_reg`

Comment: Well that tells you what the error is; insufficient PHP memory.... either increase the memory available to PHP via your php.ini file, or try using some of PHPExcel's memory reduction techniques such as cell caching

Comment: @MarkBaker - I increased the memory limit and I got it to generate a pdf file for me. Mpdf is generating everything in the Excel file including the empty columns up to the last column in an Excel file.

Comment: @MarkBaker I worked it out. The pdf file was too large because I was setting the width of all the columns up to ZZ and Mpdf is print all of that on one page. So it a very tiny spread grid for a spread sheet. I will have to find a PDF library that prints like MS Excel. Any ideas?